# Memory Recording between adb and MAT(Eclipse Memory Analyzer)?

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, profiling, out-of-memory

I took out a memory analysis of my android game using MAT(Eclipse) and by using "command adb shell dumpsys meminfo ".MAT is reporting total of 9m heap size allocated to my application whereas the adb is reporting the allocated memory(Dalvik Heap allocated memory) much more than that ? 
I am testing on Samsung Galaxy S2 (Icecream Sandwich).Does MAT accurately display the allocated heap size ???

Thank you all in advance :)